# I can't create layout with specific width and height in dp

Tags: android, android-layout

I will try to create a specific layout to Samsung Galaxy S8. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

I made a specific **folder** following Android documentation 
**layout-w360dp-h740dp**.
I can see in Android Studio into Design this work
[image]

But with the simulator and real device don´t get the specific layout.

Thanks!

Comment: simple give height width to your main layout and get solution.

Comment: Hi @kevanaghera, I made a specific folder following Android documentation layout-w360dp-h740dp

Comment: Do the files within `/layout` and `/layout-w360dp-h740dp` definitely have the same name?

Comment: Hi! @billynomates. Yes, The files have the same name